# Akka.net - Reconnect of remote actor

Tags: akka.net

Just if i miss something a question regarding Akka.Net and a remote Actor scenario.

If i implement an Actor A (local) and deploying an Actor B (remote), and afterwards sending a Message from A to B it is totally easy.

After sending a Message, B tells A a result (at some point later).
For that reason, we are switching A with a Behavior into a "waiting" state.

Also, that works like a charm, but what can happen is that B is going down for any reason.
If so, A is waiting forever for an answer and will freeze in this state.

How is such a situation handled correctly / how should it be designed?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Idiomatic message-based approach**: when changing behavior into `Waiting` state, actor can schedule message to itself (`Context.System.Scheduler.ScheduleTellOnceCancellable(timeout, Self, cancelMessage, ActorRefs.NoSender)`), which will trigger after desired timeout. So, a waiting actor behavior will react on the response or cancellation, and i.e. stash all other messages - unstashing can happen after response or cancellation is handled.
2. **Non-idiomatic**, probably also more expensive (in terms of CPU/memory), but simpler: simply use `targetActor.Ask<Response>(request, timeout)`. You can also setup global timeout from HOCON config: `akka.actor.ask-timeout = 10s`.